# Деструктуризация объекта, при отдаче в мутации, выдает undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue3

почему, когда при деструктуризации отдаю grade, прилетает undefined, хотя id прилетает норм

```
methods:{
setRating(id, grade){
  grade = this.mark
  console.log(grade, 'это установка')
  this.$store.dispatch('products/setRating', {id, grade})
},
getMark(mark){
  this.mark = mark
  console.log(this.mark, 'это получение')
  return this.mark
}
}
```

вот что в компоненте

```
<div class="col">
  Your rating
    <i 
    v-for="num in max"
    :key="num"
    :class="{ 'rating-color': num <= value  }"
    @click="$emit('update:value', num), getMark(num)"
  >&#9734;</i>
  <div class="col">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="setRating(id)">Send</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

в сторе есть вот такой экшн, который получает ключики моего деструктурированного объекта, выше через мутацию, закидывается значение в state

```
async setRating({commit}, {id, grade}){
  await productsApi.setRating({id, grade})
  commit('setRating', {id, grade})
}
```

Крайний console.log идет от папочки с запросами на api, вот сам запрос

```
 export async function setRating({id, num}){
  await http.put('ratings.php', {
    id: {id},
    mark: {num},
    errorAlert: 'при попытке оценки товара. Авторизируйтесь!'
  })
  console.log(id, '-id', num, '-rating')
}
```

Может конечно я что упускаю, но где может быть проблема...

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки.

Comment: пофиксил ошибку, в функции, которая делала запрос на api, передавал неверное название ключа, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

пофиксил ошибку, в функции, которая делала запрос на api, передавал неверное название ключа

Comment: Зачем делать и ответ, и комментарий? Одного комментария было вполне достаточно)